# Excel VBA macro - Change link name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel macro routine that I need to prep a file for another routine which is run daily. This prepping involves changes the links of t-1 file to a t0 file.

The code I usually do is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
        "file path", NewName:=new_file_path, Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

My trouble now is that for this particular routine the file path to be changed to a new routine is not always the same, thus I would need a way to automatize finding out what are the current links to replace them all. The new file path I now because it is the worksheet that is calling this routine and opening this file, so first thing I do Is

```
new_file_path = "C:\...."& ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xlsm"
```

What would help me is if there is a trick to replace all links for a new one, without the need to say the name/path of the old links. Does any one know?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this helps. `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` for returning the path and name of current workbook. `ActiveWorkbook.Path` for returning the path only.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not my issue. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

To change all the excel links in a workbook try this procedure:

```
    Sub WbThs_ChangeLink_Excel()
    Dim wbTrg As Workbook
    Dim sLinkNew As String
    Dim aLinks As Variant, vLink As Variant

        sLinkNew = "@@VBA Links Replace - Target 3.xlsb"   'Change as required

        Set wbTrg = ThisWorkbook   'Change as required

        Rem Set array with all excel links
        aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)

        Rem Replace each excel Link
        If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
            For Each vLink In aLinks
                wbTrg.ChangeLink Name:=vLink, NewName:=sLinkNew, Type:=xlExcelLinks

        Next: End If

        End Sub
```

See the following pages for additional information on the resources used:
[Workbook.ChangeLink Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/workbook-changelink-method-excel)
[Workbook.LinkSources Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/workbook-linksources-method-excel)
[XlLink Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/xllink-enumeration-excel)